# How to create multiple file based on the size of the file in a nested for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am writing a Python script for creating multiple files based on the file size.

For example:

Create a another file when the size becomes 10MB.

In regards to the sample script that contains what I have tried so far, it is creating multiple files but not based on the size:

```
global fname
x=1
def IP():
    limit = 1
    i= 255
    for j in range(1,3):
        fname = "new_file"+str(x)+".txt"
        global x
        x += 1
        with open(fname, "a") as new:
            for k in range(1,200):
                for l in range(1,200):
                    new.write("IP is: %d.%d.%d.%d\n"%(i,j,k,l))                            
IP() 
IP()
```

**Output:**

```
new_file1.txt
new_file2.txt
```

Comment: Please correct your code indentation, which is important in Python.

Comment: yeah but while posting the question it was not allowing me to do that. Let me try again. I have done that

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test your file. You might need to use `.flush()` to force writing the files content physically before checking its size, else the OS decides when to flush it - wich might be at 4k or 8k data in the buffer.

```
import os
import random 

def rnd():
    r = random.randint
    return [r(1,255),r(1,255),r(1,255),r(1,255)]

x = 1
while True:
    with open("myfile_{}.txt".format(x),"a") as f:
        x += 1
        # reads flushed sizes only
        while os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size < 300: # size criterium
            f.write("{}.{}.{}.{}\n".format(*rnd()))
            f.flush() # persist to disk so size checking works - this degrades performance
        if x > 10:
            break

for f in os.listdir("./"):
    print(f, os.stat(f).st_size)
```

Output:

```
myfile_10.txt 304
myfile_9.txt 315
myfile_8.txt 313
myfile_4.txt 302
myfile_6.txt 305
myfile_2.txt 306
myfile_5.txt 300
main.py 447
myfile_7.txt 308
myfile_3.txt 303
myfile_1.txt 304
```

If you just need a guesstimate, you could also use the file-handles `.tell()` method to get the position inside the stream you are currently writing. This is *not* the file size though.

Comment: Thanks you so much that worked and its also a efficient code too but can you please do the same for the sample script what i have posted using nested for loops. Because i just wanted to know how that can be applied on that also